# Get array from session, update it, then how to update session?

Tags: php, arrays, session, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

My gut tells me this code won't update the array in the session. Is that correct?

```
foreach ($_SESSION['accts'] as $acctId => $acct)
  $acct['someNewKey'] = 'hi mom!';

// Later, another page...

foreach ($_SESSION['accts'] as $acct)
  echo $acct['someNewKey'];
```

Will this output **hi mom!**?

Comment: *"Will this output hi mom!?"* - You tell us, did it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: My question isn't about foreach. I also don't care how many times hi mom! is output> @Arif_suhail_123 what do you mean I am creating another session value?

Comment: Your question actually *is* about `foreach`. Look what the manual says about it and using references.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't update your session data, because what you're modifying here is a copy of the array.

Try this instead

```
foreach($_SESSION['accts'] as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['accts'][$key]['someNewKey'] = 'hi mom!';
}
```